# React server rendering - how to use JSX?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning server-side rendering in React from this sample code: https://github.com/zertosh/ssr-demo-kit/blob/master/minimal/main.js

It's working great. But now I'm trying to rewrite the render method to use JSX, that's all. What do I have to do to make it work? I tried to look in many places, used node-jsx, but it didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: node-jsx definitely works (I use it), so there's likely some configuration wrong somewhere. Can you expand your question to include the node-jsx details?

Comment: Maybe it happens because I don't use node-jsx correctly. All I did is that I added this line to the sent file right after the line requiring ExecutionEnvironment: require("node-jsx").install({harmony: true}); - should I do something else?

Comment: By the time you install node-jsx, it's too late—you're already in a JSX file. You need to install it in a non-JSX file and then require a JSX file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use reactify to build the code and then start the server

After converting main.js in the demo to jsx, run these commands

```
 npm install reactify
 browserify -t reactify main.js --standalone Application --debug --outfile main-built.js
 npm start
```